# Revert the swipe in Android Recycler view ItemTouchHelper with animation

Tags: android, animation, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I have implemented swipe with ItemTouchHelper and it works properly. In some cases I want to keep the swiped item back in the recycler view and not remove it, this part is also working fine but just makes the item to reappear. I want to bring back the item with animation just like swipe, as if the swipe is done in opposite direction with same item. Is there a way to revert that swipe along with the swipe animation of view holder after onSwiped is called?

Answer (score 3):

Do it simply by adding this line

```
 @Override
  public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                    Log.e(TAG,"left Swipe");
                }else {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Right Swipe");
                }
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
```